# Cannot transfer value to another class ( c# )

Tags: nullreferenceexception

I have the first class named:

```
            Appartments[] appartments;
```

I want to copy the value of "Number" and paste it to "AppartmentInfo.cs" class( I guess they are called Parameters).

```
        public static void FindFloor(Appartments[] appartments, int amount,out int floorToRound,out AppartmentInfo[] AInfo)
    {
        floorToRound = 0;
        AInfo = new AppartmentInfo[Max];
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            AInfo[i].Floor1 = Convert.ToDouble(appartments[i].Number);
            Console.WriteLine(appartments[i].Number);
            if (appartments[i].Number < 27)
            {
                appartments[i].Number = 1;
            }
            else
            {

                appartments[i].Number /= 27;
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is a need I can post the whole code. I get the error:
NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Error on the line:

```
AInfo[i].Floor1 = Convert.ToDouble(appartments[i].Number);
```

---

FULL CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace P3._1
 {
class Program
{
    public const int Max = 20;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int amount, AmountOfRooms, price, floor, floorToRound;
        Appartments[] appartments;
        AppartmentInfo[] AInfo;
        //AppartmentInfo AInfo = new AppartmentInfo();
        ReadData(out appartments, out amount);
        TextImput(out floor, out AmountOfRooms, out price);
        FindFloor(appartments, amount,out floorToRound,out AInfo);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void ReadData(out Appartments[] appartments, out int amount)
    {
        amount = 0;
        appartments = new Appartments[Max];
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P3\\P3.1 be konstruktoriaus\\Appartments.csv", true))
        {
            reader.ReadLine();
            string line = null;
            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                int number = int.Parse(values[0]);
                int area = int.Parse(values[1]);
                int rooms = int.Parse(values[2]);
                int sellingCost = int.Parse(values[3]);
                int phone = int.Parse(values[4]);

                Appartments appartmentsObj = new Appartments(number, area, rooms, sellingCost, phone);
                appartments[amount++] = appartmentsObj;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void TextImput(out int floor, out int AmountOfRooms, out int price)
    {
        AmountOfRooms = 0;
        price = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Iveskite buto aukštą: ");
        floor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Iveskite kambariu skaiciu: ");
        AmountOfRooms = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Maksimali kaina: ");
        price = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


    }

    public static void FindFloor(Appartments[] appartments, int amount,out int floorToRound,out AppartmentInfo[] AInfo)
    {
        floorToRound = 0;
        AInfo = new AppartmentInfo[Max];
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            AInfo[i].Floor1 = Convert.ToDouble(appartments[i].Number);
            Console.WriteLine(appartments[i].Number);
            if (appartments[i].Number < 27)
            {
                appartments[i].Number = 1;
            }
            else
            {

                appartments[i].Number /= 27;
            }
        }
    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access the `AInfo[i].Floor1` property but if `AppartmentInfo`  is a class, then each element in your `AInfo` array will be `null`. You would need to create an `AppartmentInfo` object first:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        AInfo[i] = new AppartmentInfo
        {
            Floor1 = Convert.ToDouble(appartments[i].Number)
        };
```

---

**Edit/Update**: Complete/compilable program to demonstrate the syntax:

```
public class Program
{       
    public static void Main()
    {
        var meow = new Foo[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            meow[i] = new Foo
            {
                Bar = Convert.ToDouble("3.141"),
                Blah = "Another Test",
            };              

            if (i < 2)
            {
                meow[i].Buzz = 3;
            }
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public double Bar { get; set; }
        public string Blah { get; set; }
        public int Buzz { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I do have one more question. Is there an easier way to create an AppartmentInfo object? For example I need to transfer not only "Floor1", but also "Rooms', "Price", and many other things..also I need to check what to transfer and what not, so I need to use IF, however I cannot use IF inside  AInfo[i] = new AppartmentInfo
        { } this.

Comment: @Andrius You can set multiple properties inside the `{ }` by using a comma `,` to separate each property.     If you need an `if` check, then you can still set the properties after you have created the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop iterates from zero to amount - 1 then tries to look up the array entry in Appartments array for that index.

It is likely that the value passed in for the amount field is bigger than the size of the apartments array.

Hard to say without knowing what the apartments array looks like and what value is in the amount parameter.

Comment: from my view,  amount never passes boundaries.I just uploaded full code

Comment: Does it fail on the first iteration of the for loop?

Comment: I ask because I was following the same line of thought as Bens answer describes. He has it correct. Your array is initialized but the elements in it are not.